# Create a keyboard that has only Apple Emojis? iOS - Swift 3

Tags: xcode, keyboard, swift3, emoji, custom-keyboard

I would like to create a keyboard that only has emojis. What is the best way to accomplish this? I know I could just create something that looks like a keyboard that was a collection view of emoji images but I'd much rather use the built in emojis(unicode).

Comment: This question is too broad.  What have you tried already?  Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Comment: I'd like to have a keyboard pop up when a textfield is selected. I don't want that keyboard to have any available characters besides emojis.

Comment: did you have any success?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you will have to build your own custom keyboard! It's fun and easy to create once you do a little research.

But as for your answer, there is no preset keyboard that gives you what you are asking for.